# Symfony: Entities and Class Implements

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Suppose I want to have two entities in my database, a Box and an Object. I can have different boxes and within each box I can add multiple Objects.
(For simplicity, I've missed out the getters, setters, $id, etc in the code examples)

**Box entity**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
class Box {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedby="box")
     */
    private $objects;
    }
```

**Object entity**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
class Object {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Box", mappedby="objects")
     */
    private $box;

    // The following are assumptions
    private $objectType;
    private $objectData;
    private $theObject;
}
```

My objects can be multiple types (I want to be able to add new types of objects without touching the database):

**A Pen (not an Entity)**

```
class Pen implements ObjectType {
    public $color; // In reality this would have set/get

    public function whatAmI() {
        return "I am a ".$this->color." pen";
    }
}
```

**A Remote (not an Entity)**

```
class Remote implements ObjectType {
    public $numberOfButtons;

    public function whatAmI() {
        return "I am a remote with ".$this->numberOfButtons." buttons";
    }

    public function pressButton() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**ObjectType**

```
interface ObjectType {
    public function whatAmI();
}
```

My question is what is the best way to tie the two bits together? I would like to be able to do the following:

Go through all the objects in my box and call functions which they implement:

```
$myBox = $em->find('Box', $id);

foreach ($myBox->getObjects() as $object) {
    echo $object->whatAmI();
}
```

Create a new object and add it to my box:

```
$myPen = new Pen();
$myPen->color = "red";

$myBox->addObject($myPen);
```

Call functions if I fetch the object directly from the DB:

```
$myRemote = find('Object', $id); // $id will be of a Remote class
$myRemote->pressButton();
```

Comment: P.S, please edit or suggest a better title for this question.

Comment: possibly a conditional based on what the class is an instance of seems like the most straightforward.. `if ($obj instanceof 'Remote') { $obj->pushButton() }`

Comment: You also might want to look at Doctrine Inheritance.